# My swift static framework is doesn't work in OC file with iphone simulator

Tags: ios, swift, static, frameworks

I have made a static framework that mix of Swift and OC， and it includes Architectures:  "armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64".
[image: Architectures]

it also includes all .swiftmodule file:
[image]

it works well with real device or in swift file for real device and simulator.

but **only** when i use framework's swift class in the Objective-C file and target device is iphone simulator, it will give me an error:
[image]

the BaseNavigationController(write in swift), BaseViewController(write in OC) are my framework classes, only the swift class doesn't work, the BaseNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController with 'open' level access control, and the framework '-Swift.h' file has generated oc interface.

Why does it report an error？I checked my project carefully，but no exception found。

my xcode version is： Version 11.5 (11E608c)， and project build_setting's swift version is 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is very likely in the build script that is used.
The issue here might be that after using lipo to merge the framework built for devices(`armv7` & `arm64` architectures) and simulators(`i386`, `x86_64`) architectures, **you should also copy contents of the `BaseCore-Swift.h` generated for the simulator to the one generated for `armv7` & `arm64` architectures**.

Objective-C requires symbols to be defined for i386 and x86_64 architectures in the `BaseCore-Swift.h` file for Swift classes to work. This file can be found within the **Headers** folder after you perform a build.
You could simply use the `cat` command to perform this copy within your build script if you have one.

The issue here is not that architectures for the simulator are not included, but that the symbols are not defined in the `BaseCore-Swift.h` file for simulator architectures so Objective-C can pick them up.

Please feel free to comment or ask additional queries.

If doing the above solves your issue, please mark this as accepted :)

Comment: Awesome！Your answer perfectly solved my problem.A closer inspection reveals that there is a line of code above the ‘-Swift’ file: `#if 0
#elif defined(__arm64__) && __arm64__`. Hey, brother, in which document did you find the description that need to copy the `-Swif.h` file, or does the official provide complete documentation for creating a Swift static library?